# How to replace the bootstrapmodule app on the fly

Tags: angular, angular14

I have want to show a "work-in-progress" page on our angular website, which has a totally different layout than the "upcoming-website".

**Objective**

- I want to create a button on that "work-in-progress" page which is sending me to the upcoming website's main page (same angular application).

If someone clicks that button, how can I replace the current `bootstrapModule` with the new one upcoming-website's module?

In the future, I will update the app and completely remove the "work-in-progress" page and by default set the "upcoming-website" as default.

(I don't want to create 2 Angular apps for some specific reasons. And the 2 "apps" have complete different html layout and css files).

Comment: Why not simply use routing? If you already have two modules, simply load `upcoming-website` on user click.

Comment: @WillAlexander yes, that is an option. then you kind of have 2 top level routes and the rest of the routers are are children to the upcoming-website. I just dislike that, but yes, I guess it is not wrong. Any more thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Why do you "dislike" it? You don't even need to do two top-level routes. You can simply create a "work-in-progress" route which is the default route.